# Add days to timestamp

Tags: c#, json, api, unix, json.net

I need to add one day to unix timestamp. I got timestamp from API: `unixDate = (string)result["dt"];` , result: `1617789600`. But now I need to add one day to it. How can I do it?

```
   public static List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>> euDataDaily(string url)
   {
        var aTuple = new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string>> { };
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        var data = c.DownloadString(url);
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

        string conditionCode="";
        string unixDate = "";
        string dayTemp="";

        foreach (var result in o["daily"])
        {
               unixDate = (string)result["dt"];

               dayTemp = (string)result["temp"]["day"];

               foreach (var resultas in result["weather"])
               {
                    conditionCode = (string)resultas["icon"];
               }                   
        }
        List<Tuple<string, string>> icon = convertIcon(conditionCode);

        foreach (var tuple in icon)
        {
              aTuple.Add(Tuple.Create(dayTemp, tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, unixDate));
        }
              return aTuple;
   }
```

JSON example:

```
   {
      "daily": [
        {
          "dt": 1595268000,
          "sunrise": 1608124431,
          "sunset": 1608160224,
          "temp": {
            "day": 278.14,
            "min": 273.15,
            "max": 279.4,
            "night": 273.15,
            "eve": 275.82,
            "morn": 275.35
          },
          "weather": {
            "clouds": 60,
            "pop": 0.84,
            "uvi": 2.41,
            "icon": "cloudy.gif"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try parsing `unixStamp` to a DateTime, call the DateTime method AddDays(1) and then convert it back to a unix timestamp string. Link to AddDays docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=net-5.0

Comment: `DateTimeOffset` has methods for dealing with Unix Epoch time. Though since it's seconds, you could simply add 86400 seconds (i.e. 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours).

Comment: Just to be sure, is this Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: Yes, is it Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using JObject, you can cast it to an int instead of a string. If you swap out `unixDate = (string)result["dt"];` for `unixDate = (int)result["dt"];`, you'll have the same number but in a int instead of a string. Then you can just add 86400(a day in seconds) and convert it back to a string with `ToString()`.

Do note that, `(int)` cast does **not** work for normal strings, it's specific to JObject. If you try to do this on a normal string you'll get `InvalidCastException`. For normal strings go for [`int.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-5.0)(or [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0)) instead.